# How to write a advice which will inject for all the DAO classes which is annotated with @Repository

Tags: spring

When I tried to find the answer for "difference between @component,@service,@Repository,@controller" I found one additional answer "It will help in case of AOP when you separate the layers by using these annotation.

For example if you want to inject one Aspect of logging (before,after)to all the DAO,you are able to do that using AOP as you have three distinct Layers and are not mixed.

Can anyone please suggest me the sample code how to write join points which will apply to all @Repository by using this annotation.I know how to create joint points with the help of expressions,autoproxycreater(which will tell inject advice whose method matches the advisor's pointcut) but how we will tell to inject advice to all the classes which is annotated with @Repository.

Answer (score 0):

The following pointcut expression to advice based on annotation `@target(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository)` should help.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: 


```
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer
```